# Can value "literals" be combined with select statements in an "INSERT INTO"

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, insert, derby

this is my first post here so please accept my apologies in advance if anything is out of place.
I am also a newbie trying to learn a bit of Java and JDBC. I would like to know if it possible to combine hard-coded values with select statements in a SQL  INSERT INTO.
I am trying the statement below which gives me this error "Scalar subquery is only allowed to return a single row."
Thanks in advance for any advice.

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO MEMBER_LESSONS "
                + " (LESSON_ID, BOOKING_DT, LESSON_DT, LESSON_TIME, LESSON_FEE, MEMBER_ID_FK,PRO_ID_FK)"
                + " VALUES (DEFAULT, '2020-01-10', '2020-01-15', '14:00', 50.0,"
                + " (SELECT ml.MEMBER_ID_FK FROM  MEMBERS m inner join MEMBER_LESSONS ml on ml.MEMBER_ID_FK = m.MEMBER_ID"
                + " where m.MEMB_NAME = ?),"
                + " (SELECT ml.PRO_ID_FK FROM GOLF_PRO gp inner join MEMBER_LESSONS ml on ml.PRO_ID_FK = gp.PRO_ID"
                + " AND gp.PRO_NAME = 'Tiger Dojen'))";
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your kind assistance. I am up and running now thanks to you.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't really a Java issue.  Your SQL would fail if you entered it directly into an SQL client.  Each of those subselects is returning multiple rows, whereas if each just returned a single row, the SQL would work fine.

You've got some unnecessary joins in there.  You could just write

```
"INSERT INTO MEMBER_LESSONS "
                + " (LESSON_ID, BOOKING_DT, LESSON_DT, LESSON_TIME, LESSON_FEE, MEMBER_ID_FK,PRO_ID_FK)"
                + " VALUES (DEFAULT, '2020-01-10', '2020-01-15', '14:00', 50.0,"
                + " (SELECT m.MEMBER_ID FROM  MEMBERS m WHERE m.MEMB_NAME = ?),"
                + " (SELECT gp.PRO_ID FROM GOLF_PRO gp WHERE gp.PRO_NAME = 'Tiger Dojen'))";
```

or even

```
"INSERT INTO MEMBER_LESSONS "
                + " (BOOKING_DT, LESSON_DT, LESSON_TIME, LESSON_FEE, MEMBER_ID_FK,PRO_ID_FK) "
                + "SELECT '2020-01-10', '2020-01-15', '14:00', 50.0, m.MEMBER_ID, gp.PRO_ID "
                + "FROM  MEMBERS m, GOLF_PRO gp "
                + "WHERE m.MEMB_NAME = ? AND gp.PRO_NAME = 'Tiger Dojen'";
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  Your code is a bit hard to follow, but you can dispense with the values.  Something like this:

```
INSERT INTO MEMBER_LESSONS (BOOKING_DT, LESSON_DT, LESSON_TIME, LESSON_FEE, MEMBER_ID_FK,PRO_ID_FK)
    SELECT '2020-01-10', '2020-01-15', '14:00', 50.0, 
           (SELECT ml.MEMBER_ID_FK
            FROM MEMBERS m 
            WHERE m.MEMB_NAME = ?
           ),
           (SELECT ml.PRO_ID_FK
            FROM GOLF_PRO gp 
            WHERE gp.PRO_NAME = 'Tiger Dojen'
           )
```

Notes:

- I removed `LESSON_ID` from the column list and `DEFAULT` from the `SELECT`.
- I removed the JOINs in the subqueries; they don't seem necessary.
- You don't specify the database you are using.  Some might require a `from` clause, such as `from dual`.